# What does "Clear Of Clouds" mean in reference to Class B Airspace in the United States?

Tags: faa-regulations, class-b-airspace

Does "clear of clouds" mean you cannot touch a cloud or does it mean that that Class B airspace must not have any clouds in it?

Comment: What is the full context?  Did you read this in a briefing? Receive it as an Instruction from ATC?

Comment: Related: [What does “clear of clouds” mean in FAA FAR part 103?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16976/what-does-clear-of-clouds-mean-in-faa-far-part-103?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That specific phrasing means that you can't touch a cloud. See the VFR minimums in [14 CFR 91.155](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=14:2.0.1.3.10#se14.2.91_1155), where it says:

> no person may operate an aircraft under VFR when the flight visibility
>   is less, or at a distance from clouds that is less, than that
>   prescribed for the corresponding altitude and class of airspace in the
>   following table [...]

The table lists the "distance from clouds" in class B as "clear of clouds".

You can also find it in the [AIM section 3-2-3](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/AIM.pdf) on class B airspace, and in other sections about SVFR, visual approaches etc. where a requirement for those procedures is to remain clear of clouds.

The actual cloud cover in the class B airspace is reported by METARs and ATIS.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the pilot should not touch the clouds in VFR. From CFR [91.115](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=dca6a2ec1a68a68db444d85d333641f1&mc=true&node=se14.2.91_1155&rgn=div8):

[image: VFR]